# Why do several Angular component libraries make modals and dialogs work through a service?

Tags: css, angular, html, typescript

I've been doing a lot of research for an Angular based internal component library we are building and I can't seem to find why a Modal or Dialog component requires the abstraction of a Service to work. I have a working example simply using an approach of an Angular component with some CSS to make it be where it needs to be on the page, using content projection to make the code reusable.

I basically want to understand what hidden funtionality/benefits there are to using a service to call/generate the modal since every Angular based component library I've come across uses this method.

Comment: Are you talking about a service to create a modal? Or a service to allow your modal to communicate with your controller?

Comment: A little of both: So I would call some function in the service and that function would generate the modal with some templateRef or componentRef as the primary content. The service would also allow some data to be passed from the component to the modal and vice versa.

Comment: I don't think there is a right answer to this. If you have clean, maintainable, unrepeated code which does the job then thats great. A service pattern provides a clean way to create a third party component, but without looking into their code its hard to know whether it was necessary to use the service pattern or just a choice they made. Certainly my first thought would be to use a service pattern, because it separate concerns and provides a flexible solution. But doesn't mean its better for you.